# Why only main thread can set signal handler in Python

Tags: python

In python's signal handling semantics, only main thread can set signal handler, and only main thread can invoke signal handler.

Why design like this?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the ability of threads to terminate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This comment appears in the cpython sourcefile [signalmodule.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/signalmodule.c#L63):

> /*    NOTES ON THE INTERACTION BETWEEN SIGNALS AND THREADS
>
> When threads are supported, we want the following semantics:
>
> - only the main thread can set a signal handler
> - any thread can get a signal handler
> - signals are only delivered to the main thread
>
> I.e. we don't support "synchronous signals" like SIGFPE (catching
>   this doesn't make much sense in Python anyway) nor do we support
>   signals as a means of inter-thread communication, since not all
>   thread implementations support that (at least our thread library
>   doesn't).
>
> We still have the problem that in some implementations signals
>   generated by the keyboard (e.g. SIGINT) are delivered to all
>   threads (e.g. SGI), while in others (e.g. Solaris) such signals are
>   delivered to one random thread (an intermediate possibility would
>   be to deliver it to the main thread -- POSIX?).  For now, we have    a
>   working implementation that works in all three cases -- the    handler
>   ignores signals if getpid() isn't the same as in the main    thread.
>
> XXX This is a hack.
>
> */

My reading of this is that the limitation on setting signal handlers is to simplify the implmentation of signal handling in cpython, by avoiding having to cope with differences in os-level signal implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Because Python `signal` module implement it that way. I believe partly because there is no easy way(if any) to lock GIL from non-main thread by signal handler. So I would rather say it's GIL limitation.

You might be interested in this: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

Comment: "I believe partly because there is no easy way(if any) to lock GIL from non-main thread" - on the contrary, it is easy to lock the GIL from non-main threads, and it is outright mandatory for any thread to lock the GIL while it is executing Python code.